# PostgreSQL regexp_replace() to keep just one whitespace

Tags: regex, string, postgresql, replace, whitespace

I need to clean up a string column with both whitespaces and tabs included within, at the beginning or at the end of strings (it's a mess !). I want to keep just one whitespace between each word. Say we have the following string that includes every possible situation :

```
mystring = '  one two    three      four    '
```

- 2 whitespaces before 'one'
- 1 whitespace between 'one' and 'two'
- 4 whitespaces between 'two' and 'three'
- 2 tabs after 'three'
- 1 tab after 'four'

Here is the way I do it :

1. I delete leading and trailing whitespaces
2. I delete leading and trailing tabs
3. I replace both 'whitespaces repeated at least two' and tabs by a sole whitespace

```
WITH

  t1 AS (SELECT'  one two    three      four    '::TEXT AS mystring),

  t2 AS (SELECT TRIM(both ' ' from mystring) AS mystring FROM t1),

  t3 AS (SELECT TRIM(both '\t' from mystring) AS mystring FROM t2)

  SELECT regexp_replace(mystring, '(( ){2,}|\t+)', ' ', 'g') FROM t3 ;
```

I eventually get the following string, which looks nice but I still have a trailing whitespace...

```
'one two three four '
```

Any idea on doing it in a more simple way and solving this last issue ?

Many thanks !

Comment: Any help ? Someone posted a comment yesterday and deleted it... I've had no time to look at it. Thanks !

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
SELECT trim(regexp_replace(col_name, '\s+', ' ', 'g')) as col_name FROM table_name;
```

Or In case of update :

```
UPDATE table_name SET col_name = trim(regexp_replace(col_name, '\s+', ' ', 'g'));
```

The `regexp_replace` is flags are described on [this section](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP) of the documentation.

Comment: On Postgres 9.5 use `\s` instead of `\\s`.

Comment: On Postgres 9.4 and 10.0 it also seems that `\s` should be used rather than `\\s`.

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT trim(regexp_replace(mystring, '\s+', ' ', 'g')) as mystring FROM t1;`

Posting an answer in case folks don't look at comments.

Use `'\s+'`

Not `'\\s+'`

Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work for me with `trim` and `regexp_replace`. So I came with another solution:

```
SELECT trim(
    array_to_string(
        regexp_split_to_array('  test    with many  spaces  for        this   test  ', E'\\s+')
    , ' ')
) as mystring;
```

First `regexp_split_to_array` eliminates all spaces leaving "blanks" at the beginning and the end.

```
-- regexp_split_to_array output:
-- {"",test,with,many,spaces,for,this,test,""}
```

When `using array_to_string` all the ',' become spaces

```
-- regexp_split_to_array output ( '_' instead of spaces for viewing ):
-- _test_with_many_spaces_for_this_test_
```

The trim is to remove the head and tail

```
-- trim output ( '_' instead of spaces for viewing ):
-- test_with_many_spaces_for_this_test
```