# How to remove white spaces for column value in database

Tags: postgresql, twitter

I am collecting tweets from twitter and storing them in database. In those tweets some of the tweets are coming with greater white space. When I am storing those tweets into database it is shown in the below picture.

[image: How to remove the white spaces as shown]

I tried to remove the white spaces using regex. Here is the query

```
SELECT '(' || REGEXP_REPLACE(text, E'[[:space:]]', '', 'g') || ')'FROM persons;
```

I am getting the following output

```
**OUTPUT :** ('RT@Cristiano:Grandejogodetodaaequipa.Vencemosjuntos,celebramosjuntos.@realmadrid#HalaMadrid#RMClasico:soccer::grinning::muscle::v::facepunch:https://t.co/…')
```

In the above output when i tried using reg-ex, the original spaces are missing out. Now how to store the data by getting as a neat english text with regular spaces (i.e., removing white spaces,tabs).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL regexp\_replace() to keep just one whitespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25912388/postgresql-regexp-replace-to-keep-just-one-whitespace)

Comment: You can write it little bit simpler:
SELECT '(' || regexp_replace(text, '\s' , '', 'g') || ')' FROM persons;